# There is a way I can list the export values by stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I see this function https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/list-exports.html but it will return all the export values from the entire account/region, I just want to get the export values to a given stack, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [describe-stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html).

For example, the following will display only outputs which export something:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name <your-stack-name> --query "Stacks[0].Outputs[?ExportName]"
```